Windbg preview version load pykd get Win32 error 0n126
I'm trying to load PyKd module on Windbg preview version. It would show up the win32 error message as below.
0: kd> .load pykd_script\Release_3.8\pykd.pyd
The call to LoadLibrary(C:\Apps\pykd_script\Release_3.8\pykd.pyd) failed, Win32 error 0n126
    "The specified module could not be found."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.

However, the folder does really contain the pykd.pyd module.
Then, I'm trying load Pykd on Windbg lagacy version. It works fine.
It wouldn't get any error message.
My environment is set correctly with the Python path.
I'm expecting that the pykd.pyd should load successfully on Windbg preview version.

Are you mixing 32 bit and/or 64 bit? Do you have the correct Python version installed as well? You need 32 bit WinDbg + 32 bit pykd + 32 bit Python or 64 bit WinDbg + 64 bit pykd + 64 bit Python.

Hi, Thomas, I used 64 bit WinDbg + 64 bit pykd + 64 bit Python. Install on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/

That's a case for .dbgdbg then and see which DLL cannot be loaded.

It prints out all the dll file loaded. I found most of the dll put in system32 folder path. So, I put pykd into it and still get the same error message.  .load C:\Windows\System32\pykd.pyd
The call to LoadLibrary(C:\Windows\System32\pykd.pyd) failed, Win32 error 0n126

There's no need to put pykd in the system32 folder. Just do a .load with the full path.

As the title, however, the same error message shows up.
